# Can I clear user data in gallery?

Tags: applications, storage, insufficient-memory, gallery, cache

I've a One plus 5T and I need to take a lot of videos on my phone and even though I keep deleting them and cleaning my phone regularly the storage always seems to be full.

Apparently, my user data in gallery is taking up a lot of space, I was wondering if clearing this would also mean I'm deleting all the photos? This is the only biggest chunk that will free up a lot of space.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: On one plus 7, I noticed that deleted videos aren't permanently deleted, so I use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) and I see deleted videos on "recycle bin" and deleting from the app clears up space. Try that

Comment: Thank you. I just hope my data doesn't get deleted!

Comment: It won't if you only clear recyclable bin - you can see the files in it too and take a decision